# Some Mercurial basics

Tags: mercurial, branch

I'm having a hard time getting into Mercurial, even looking at several guides/tutorials. (It doesn't help that I panic as soon as I see command line arguments).  I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with these pretty basic questions :/

What I would like to do: 
- Obtain a copy of an existing project. (I will now refer to this copy as 'my' project and the existing project as the 'main' project).
- Then, make changes to what now is my project. I will not be uploading to the main project, however, if the main project has changes, I would like to get those integrated into my project. 
- I would like to be able to work on my project from several computers, so it can't just be local.
- I guess it's this picture: I want to do all sorts of shit on different computers with 'my'code (the green versions) while still having access to the red versions. Preferably where no one else can access my green versions.

[image: Branch example]

What I THINK I should do:
- Clone from the existing project. I should be able to integrate later updates into my branch, right?
- Somehow save that clone somewhere in a way that it still knows it's related to the main project...

TL;DR: I guess my question is: How do I make an online branch that can still receive updates?

Comment: If you are unconfortable with the command line have a look at the Workbench that comes with TortoiseHG: http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/

Comment: You're welcome to send questions to mercurial@selenic.com (subscribe [here](http://www.selenic.com/mailman/listinfo/mercurial/) or come online and [chat directly with us](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=mercurial). We might be able to help you more efficiently that way.

Answer (score 2):

Work in different clones

First create the feature clone and do some changes

```
$ hg clone project feature1
$ cd feature1
$ hg update 3
$ echo 'print("Hello feature1")' > hello.py
$ hg commit -m "Greet feature1"
```

Now check what will come in when you pull from feature1, just like you can use diff before committing. The respective command for pulling is incoming

```
$ cd ../project
$ hg incoming ../feature1
```

Note:
If you want to see the diffs, you can use hg incoming --patch just as you can do with hg log --patch for the changes in the repository.

If you like the changes, you pull them into the project

```
$ hg pull ../feature1
```

EDIT:

In Mercurial, each repository is self-contained. When you clone a repository, the new repository becomes an exact copy of the existing one at the time of the clone, but subsequent changes in either one will not show up in the other unless you explicitly transfer them, by either pulling or pushing.

From mercurial [guide](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/guide).

Comment: I'm really a noob when it comes to this, so I need some noob language... As far as I can tell, this just makes one local copy, right? What I really want is also making copies of the copy, that can update to each other, that can still get updates from the original?

Comment: As said in my edit, it will works (and it's the main interest of SCM programs). If it's still unclear, tell me, I will rearange the whole topic in something really easy.

Comment: Why do you need two local repositories? Isn’t it as simple as cloning, making your own modifications, and every time you want to integrate new changes from remote just pull and merge...

Comment: @Lauren Holst: Because I don't want other users to be bothered by my (possibly unstable) updates, but I do want to be able to work on it from different computers and have version control)...